# Adjointness of internal contravariant Hom in symmetric monoidal categories.

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let consider a closed symmetric monoidal cateogry, $\mathscr C,\otimes$, with adjunction $(X\otimes-)\dashv\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$ for all objects $X$.

The following isomorphis, valid in categories such as sets of vector spaces, over a field,
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\coprod_iX_i,Y)\cong\prod_i\mathrm{Hom}(X_i,Y)$$
leads to the following question:

The contravariant internal Hom functor $\mathrm{Hom}(-,Y)$ is also adjoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a *symmetric* (or even just braided) monoidal category, yes.

Proof:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}(A,\text{Hom}(B,C)) & \cong \mathcal{C}(A\otimes B,C) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(B \otimes A, C)\text{ via braiding } \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(B, \text{Hom}(A,C))
\end{align}$$
So, $\text{Hom}(-,C)$ is adjoint to itself on the right, just as for cartesian closure.